# How to detect ougoing call answered

Tags: android, call

I am trying to find any way to my outgoing call answered but I could not get any solution. I used BroadcastReceiver, TelephonyManager and PhoneStateLinstener but I could not get RINGING state for outgoing call. I also tried to read call log to search duration for current call but call log for the outgoing call was saved after it was finished.

I have read that it is impossible with public API. It sounds like it is possible in different way such as using internal API. I think there will be some way to do that because I can see those kind of apps on the market.

Please give me any clue and share your knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something out like below. I did that long back.

1) Register a `OutGoingCallReceiver`(Search intent Action on SO)

2) Register a `PhoneStateChangeReceiver`(intent-Action:- `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` )

3) create one flag, in `SharedPrefernces` or global `variable`.

4) Make this flag true in OutgoingCallReceiver, now when call will be be picked u ll get state as  `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`  in `PhoneStateChangeReceiver`, 
so u can figure out if this was incoming call hooked or Outgoing call hooked. disable flag at appropriate places.

You can also save onHooked time.

Comment: Thanks for reply and it is better than nothing. But... your answer is not What I want. I want to get the signal/events my call is answered.

Comment: so if state is OFF_HOOK means call is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite a late answer to this question. But I came across it today, and had an idea, so sharing it. It might help someone else who visits the post in future.

I think you can check outgoing call time of last call in PhoneStateListener class' onCallStateChanged method. Fetch the data if state is idle that is TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE.

Something like this:

```
Cursor mCallCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
int duration = mCallCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
while(mCallCursor.moveToFirst())
{   
    Toast.makeText(context, mCallCursor.getString(duration), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You can find more about that [here](http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs). I haven't tested the above code. But something like that should work.

You can check if time's 00:00, the call was not answered. Else the call was answered.

Hope this helps you.